# Vue 2 with Quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I am starting new project with Vue 2 and Quasar.
I am doing this `npm install -g @quasar/cli` , then `quasar create app-name`.
Quasar creates an application, but when I open some components,there is `setup(){ }` function. As I know it is a composition API feature and only in Vue 3. My vue-cli version is 4.5.15. How can I install Quasar, and start with Vue 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an older Quasar version, try using the package `@quasar/cli@1.2.2`

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
quasar create <folder_name> --branch v1
```

Answer (score 0):

vue2 does now support the composition api (script setup), although it wouldn't have at the time the OP asked the question
https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html

The latest quasar v1 also supports this too